# laravel unique visitor counter ip

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie. I have been coding my website for 2 weeks, and now the job is going to be finished, But I don't know how to make a simple Visitor Counter. Please help me to make a simple visitor counter.

[visitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XTPk.png)

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), and also [ask].

Comment: What @ADyson said, also, if you understand how a visitor counter could work, why not just try and start so you can ask an actual question when you're stuck?

Comment: I'm an only newbie

Comment: A simple search using your favourite search engine should provide plenty of articles and tutorials on how to do this as it is quite a common feature.

Comment: I googled everything. I still could not find it. I got tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For page views, you can simply increment a value in the database every time the page is loaded.

If you want unique visitors, you will need store a uid in a cookie and keep track of the uids.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $response = new Response();
    $existing_uid = $request->cookie('visitor_uid');
    if (! $existing_uid || Visitor::where('uid', $existing_uid)->doesntExist()) {
        $uid = Str::uuid();
        Visitor::create(['uid' => $uid]);
        $response->withCookie(cookie('visitor_uid', $uid));
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Then to display the count in a blade template:

```
Visitor Count: {{ \App\Models\Visitor::count() }}
```